# yield in to a block with call function

Tags: ruby

```
class SomeClass    

def initialize
    yield
end

def test
    puts 'test'
end 
end
```

I want to execute the test function inside a block when I initialize a some SomeClass.
    SomeClass.new { test() }
This gives me

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `test' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `instance_eval`:

```
class SomeClass    

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
  end

  def test
    puts 'test'
  end 
end

SomeClass.new { test() }    #=> test
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy, just pass the `self`:

```
class SomeClass    
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end

  def test
    puts 'test'
  end 
end

SomeClass.new { |ob| ob.test }
# >> test
```

Your one didn't work, because blocks are closure, and the `self` is set to `main` inside the block in your example. `main` is a instance of `Object`. You didn't defie the `#test` inside the `Object`, so `main` tries to call the `#test` and you got the genuine error.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use call, like this:

```
class SomeClass    

  def initialize(&block)
    block.call(self) if block_given?
  end

  def test
    puts 'test'
  end 
end

SomeClass.new {|s| s.test }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions：

## 1

```
  class SomeClass    

    def initialize(&block)
      instance_eval(&block)
    end

    def test
      puts 'test'
    end 
  end

  SomeClass.new { test() }    #=> test
```

## 2

```
  class SomeClass    

    def initialize
      yield self
    end

    def test
      puts 'test'
    end 
  end

  SomeClass.new {|o| o.test() }    #=> test
```

**Some references hope to help you:**

1.instance_eval no longer yielding self in ruby 1.9:  https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189422

2.How do I build DSLs with yield and instance_eval?: http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/11/30/how-do-i-build-dsls-with-yield-and-instance_eval/